# Efficient video workflow without multiple renders?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, video-sequence-editor, video

I'm trying to use Blender as my primary video editor, I love the concept of imposing 3d onto videos and also being able to add effects and color correction, etc. 
My problem is the workflow. I have a video with audio, I need to crop it, color correct and add text. In order to crop, I need VSE, in order to color correct, I need nodes, then I need VSE + 3D viewer for text. I don't understand how to use all of those tools without multiple renders. Right now, I crop the video, render, bring it into nodes, color correct and move from there. But soon as I import into the node editor I lose sound. I know this is probably just an ordering sort of issue or there's an obvious missing piece, but I can't figure out what it is.

To put my question succinctly:

How do I use all of Blender's video editing tools AND maintain audio without multiple renders?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do most color correction with Strip modifiers. And if you don't need 3D effects for your text, you can use Text Strips in the VSE.

There are also addons to send strips to the compositor, but it should be better to avoid them if possible.

Finally you can import your video a second time and just delete the image part of it only keeping the audio strips to solve your last problem.

You should watch the YouTube videos from Mikeycal Meyers to get a better understanding of editing videos with the VSE.